# read write file properties with PropertyHandler Shell Extension

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to create `PropertyHandler` shell extension.
What's the best way for embedding properties like (Title,Author,.....) to use the same file in multi computers or devices?
`StgCreateStorageEx ?` way or there is other ways to do it?
because `StgCreateStorageEx` dealing with `NTFS` files only and i'm not sure if the file hold these properties with it if i open it in other device with same `PropertyHandler`

Is there any way to save properties inside the my file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StgCreateStorageEx function creates a new storage object using the IStorage interface. This allows storing multiple data objects within a single binary file, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Structured_Storage. So, technically, you can save almost anything in this file including embedded properties.

I don't think that this is limited to NTFS: The old Microsoft Office .doc format (and many other Microsoft products) use this storage format and work also with FAT32.

If you want to use this binary file format is a completely different question. As you did not provide any information about the content and format of your file, I cannot recommend anything. One alternative would be to store the content of your file in an xml file. Properties like Title and Author then could be added easily.

Comment: thanck you very much
one question left :
if i use IStorage way to save properties to my file (binary content) and copy my file to other computer , is these properties still exist ?
in other way : is this IStorage created on the file and hold with my file every where in any computer device i can write this properties ?

Comment: why the new Microsoft Office .doc format (and many other Microsoft products) DO NOT use this storage format ?

Comment: IStorage creates a file and you can store file properties in the file. So, yes, the properties still exist if you copy or e-mail the file. What you probably mean are alternate data streams, see http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/alternate-streams.phtml. These exist only on NTFS and may get lost when the file is copied or e-mailed. Properties should not be stored in alternate data streams. But this is something completely different than IStorage.

Comment: Than;'s again , yes i mean : alternate data streams,

Comment: Microsoft states clearly that "Secondary streams do not provide a robust solution in which properties are guaranteed to travel with the file, and hence, the Windows Vista property system does not provide a built-in mechanism that exploits the secondary NTFS streams for property storage. ISVs are also highly discouraged from building property handlers that use secondary streams for the storage of properties." see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/building-property-handlers-properties.